# Empty UISearchbar space when combining search bar with Nav bar in iOS7?

Tags: uitableview, ios7, uisearchbar

So I was trying to combine the search bar with the Nav bar for tableview in iOS7.

I called
`self.searchDisplayController.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = YES;`
And it looks fine.

However, there is a very annoying empty space (roughly the size of a searhbar) between the nav bar and the first tableview content!

I'm wondering what exactly did I miss here?

Comment: I found a work-around method: programmatically set the searchbar's height to 0. It feels really hacky though

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by removing 2 lines of code.

`self.viewController.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;` 
`self.navigationBar.translucent = NO;`